# Error using /; matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

```
A1 = 0.85;%in^2
L = 2.0; %in
x = -2:0.5:2; %in
V1 = 300; %ft/s

for i=1 : length(x)
A = A1*cosh(x/L);
V = (V1 * A1) / A;
end
```

I know it's dumb but this is giving me this error and I can't figure out why

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in Lab2 (line 11)
V = (V1 * A1) / A;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are performing a non element-wise division between a scalar (the result of `V1 * A1`) and a vector (`A`). This should fix your problem (for more information, refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html) of the official documentation):

```
for i = 1:length(x)
    A = A1 * cosh(x / L);
    V = (V1 * A1) ./ A;
end
```

On a side note, it's not clear to me what you are attempting to do in your `for loop`. You create a vector `x` but you never really use it's values; only it's length is used in order to set the upper limit of the iteration. On the top of that, since outer scope variables never change, every single iteration produces the same `A` and `V` values. You could remove the iteration and still be able to obtain the same result with a single computation, because the inner code is already vectorized on `x`.